# Hard disk partitioning

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am completely new to ubuntu. want to get rid of my previous win 7. I have just installed ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS replacing win 7. but it is not showing my previous partitions. only one partition. I installed gparted and it is showing something like this:

/dev/sda1: ext4: 296 GiB
 /dev/sda2: extended: 1.85 GiB
 /dev/sda5: Linux-swap: 1.85 GiB

I want to make at least two new partitions for my personal files.

Please help me doing that.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! What is the name of your partitions, i.e how are they mounted? To know this type                               df -h in the terminal.It will show you how your partitions are mounted.

Comment: *why* do you want to create any more partitions than necessary?  Keep it simple.

Comment: Arindom, do you want to get your previous Windows 7 partitions *back*? Or do you want to have enough space to create a partition for your data files?  (You already have `swap` and `/`.  You're only missing `/home` to easily make system and data backups separately.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Fabby said, there is usually no need in extra partitions outside the Ubuntu file system. The partitions you have look totally well for a standard Ubuntu installation. You have a big partition as file system root (/) for Ubuntu and a small extended Partition containing one logical swap volume. There is nothing left from Win7 on this hard disc! But there is no remaining free unpartitioned space either.

If you really want to add new partitions, please tell us what for. You can use a separate partition mounted as your /home folder to make backups of your personal data easier. You can also outsource some other Ubuntu folders that are currently located on your main partition sda1, but I don't see any reason for this. Also, you can create new partitions formatted with a different file system such as FAT or NTFS which then is visible to non-Linux OSes like Windows without special drivers. But as you removed Win7 from your machine, there is no need for this as you won't access your hdd with anything else than Ubuntu, will you?

I possibly can give you more explanation on how to do stuff like this, but I first have to know what you want to do more exactly, okay?